# How do I set up the locale configuration on Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, locale

[The Arch Linux wiki says to run `locale -a` and modify the file `/etc/locale.gen` as first steps to setting locale on an Arch Linux system](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/locale).

However, on my system `locale -a` results in errors and the file `/etc/local.gen` does not exist. Also, the file `/etc/local.conf` does not exist either. Obviously there is some disconnect here about the assumptions the person who wrote the wiki article is making. What is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your question, you are looking for `/etc/local.conf`, however, the configuration is within `/etc/locale.conf` with a final "e". If it not exist you and you have writing permission on `/etc/`, then you can just:

```
echo LANG=en_US.UTF-8 > /etc/locale.conf
```

and that would do it, of course this is an example just with language, you can do what ever locale configuration you'd like.

Comment: yep it was a typo sorry about that, well at least you got an accepted answer :-)

Comment: `/usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED`